# Holomorphic approximation of a non-holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am looking at "near-holomorphic" continuous bounded functions defined from an open disc $D$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that the Cauchy Riemann equations aren't exactly satisfied but the conjugate partial derivative is small in some sense, for example:
$$ \left \vert \partial_{\bar{z}}f \right \vert \ll  \left \vert \partial_{z}f \right \vert \quad \text{and/or} \quad \left \vert \partial_{\bar{z}}f \right \vert \ll  \left \vert f \right \vert $$
Also, assume that partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous. I wish to know if, and under what conditions, we can express this function as a sum of a holomorphic  function and a small non-holomorphic correction:
$$ f(z,\bar{z}) \approx f_0(z) + g(z,\bar{z}) \quad \text{where} \,\, |g(z,\bar{z})|\ll |f_0(z)| \,\, \text{everywhere}$$
**Note**: I don't quite understand how considering $z$ and $\bar{z}$ as independent variables works. I wonder if I should be defining these non-holomorphic functions over $\{(z,\bar{z}) \in D \times \bar{D}\}$, and use the fact that $\bar{z}$ actually depends on $z$ at the end. I would be grateful for any help in understanding this technique(?) involving $\bar{z}$ as independent of $z$, and how to better frame this question.

If there is a power series expansion in $z$ and $\bar{z}$ about some point $z_0 (\bar{z}_0)$ in the domain that converges to $f(z,\bar{z})$ everywhere in $D$, then I believe the required result could be easier to achieve:
$$ f(z,\bar{z}) = \sum_{n,m \geq 0} \frac{(z-z_0)^n(\bar{z} - \bar{z}_0)^m}{n!m!} \partial_z^n \partial_{\bar{z}}^m f|_{(z_0,\bar{z}_0)}  = f(z,\bar{z}_0) + (\bar{z} - \bar{z}_0)\partial_{\bar{z}}f(z,\bar{z}_0) + (\text{negligible higher-order derivatives})$$
where the $f(z,\bar{z}_0)$ is the holomorphic part and the second term is the small correction.

When is such an expansion valid for non-holomorphic functions?

**Edit 1:** I found a resource ([research paper](https://jkms.kms.or.kr/journal/view.html?spage=423&volume=40&number=3)) that I believe is trying to prove a much harder general version of what I want to do. The most relevant part is the following excerpts from section 1.
The question they want to solve:

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a complex manifold, equipped with some metric, and let $\Omega$
> be a relatively compact region in $\mathcal{M}$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, does there exist
> $\delta$ > 0 such that if u is a map from the unit disc $\Delta$ (in $\mathbb{C}$) into $\Omega$, with
> $|\bar{\partial} u| ≤ \delta$, then there exists a homomorphic map $h : \Delta → \Omega$ such that
> (abusing notations) $|h − u| < \epsilon$?

The easier problem that they find trivial and that will work for me:

> For the application, it is absolutely essential that no bound be given
> on ∂u, and that no shrinking of the disc be allowed.
> If we added the hypothesis |∂u| ≤ M, then the existence (but not
> an estimate!) of δ, depending on Ω, $\epsilon$ and M, would result immediately
> from a normal family argument, arguing by contradiction

So, based on this I can reframe my question to something more cleaner looking: *Let $\Omega$
be a relatively compact region in $\mathbb{C}$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, does there exist
$\delta > 0$ such that if $u$ is a map from the unit disc $\Delta$ (in $\mathbb{C}$) into $\Omega$, with
$|\partial_{\bar{z}}u| ≤ \delta$, then there exists a homomorphic map $ h : \Delta → \Omega $ such that $d(h,u) < \epsilon$?*

And if I add the hypothesis $|\partial_z u| \leq M$, the paper itself suggests a positive answer using normal family, "arguing by contradiction". So I'm trying that.

Suppose the answer to the question (in italics) is negative. Then for any $\delta$ and $h(z)$ I choose, $d(h,u) > \epsilon_0$. Now, I have a couple of questions:

1. What's a sensible metric here for the space of 1-dimensional (complex) continuous functions defined on $\Delta$?
2. I have a feeling that I need to form a normal family $F$ of $u$ functions with $|\partial_{\bar{z}} u| < \delta$, $|\partial_{z} u| < M$ and show that the limit points of $F$ can be holomorphic. This would be the contradiction needed. Am I right?

**Edit 2:** Change the title since I am no longer looking for a power series expansion of a non-holomorphic function. But any idea in this direction would still be appreciated.